# Unwanted width attribute added to the element

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a very weird issue. I have the same code in two project. In one of them it renders as expected but in another one I see it added an unwanted `width` attribute to it and so it will be an undesired result. Why this happens?

The same code in both projects:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enter" style="margin-left: 15px"/>
```

Inspect element (in project1 it is as expected):

```
<input value="Enter" style="margin-left: 15px" type="submit">
```

Inspect element (in project2 it is not as expected. Where the `width` attribute comes from?):

```
<input value="Enter" style="margin-left: 15px; width: 640px;" type="submit">
```

Comment: There's no telling what adds the width without your asp and c# code

Comment: @Miro This has nothing to do with c#. Just a simple HTML and css question.

Comment: If it's inline (like you shared it) then it's added by something on the back end. If it's coming from a css file then search for 640 in your `style.css`. Lastly you may have a chrome plugin (Lastpass etc) that adds this. Try incognito window.

Comment: @Miro Just found this after searching: "@media (max-width: 640px){
.top-menu ul li a {
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
}"

Comment: @SteveCode This piece of code you quoted is called '**media query**' which essentially tells the browser that for as long as the width of the browser is 640px or less, it will apply the CSS rules inside the curly brackets.